# Nestjs winston azure custom transport

Tags: logging, nestjs, importerror, winston, transport

I am trying to save my nestjs application logs to azure blob storage using the winston library, I tried to create a custom transport like this:

```
import { StorageService } from "/server/storage";
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import Transport from 'winston-transport';

export class AzureTransport extends Transport {
  storageService:StorageService;
  constructor(options: any) {
    super(options);
    this.storageService=options.storageService;
    
  }

  log(info: any, callback: () => void) {
    try {   
      this.storageService.writeStreamToFile("../logs", info);
      callback();
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

But I got this error: "...can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag". I set the flag to true in my tsconfig file, but still does not work. Could anyone tell me how to create a custom transport in nestjs for winston?

I set the flag to true in my tsconfig file, but still does not work. Could anyone tell me how to create a custom transport in nestjs for winston?